# Cocos debug on window is low quality?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I don't understand why my project debugging in Window so very low quality ! I use sample project "Parkour" download on Cocos homepage ! this is its picture . (the quality on Mac is fine , but fps is sometime low )

pls see the image in here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos-debug-on-window-is-low-quality/16100

Comment: explain "low quality"

Comment: pls follow my link to see ! I can't post image here and I can't explain "low quality" by words :(